# Android weather app - can't load the Icon

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, icons, openweathermap

Trying to put the Icon to my android weather app.

```
private class DownloadImageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        return downloadImage(params[0]);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        iconView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
 private Bitmap downloadImage(String code){
        final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpGet getRequest =new HttpGet(Utils.Icon_URL + code + ".png");
        //final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("http://api.openweathermap.org/img/w/13n.png");

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                Log.e("DownloadImage", "Error:" + statusCode);
                return null;
            }
            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if(entity != null){
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return bitmap;

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
    }

}

private class WeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Weather>{
    //doInBacckgroudissa oleva koodit ajetaan taustalla. Eikä vaikuttaa muiden saikeiden ajaamista.
    @Override
    protected Weather doInBackground(String... params) {

        String data = ((new WeatherHttpClient())).getWeatherData(params[0]);
        weather.iconData = weather.currentCond.getIcon();
        weather = JsonWeatherParser.getWeather(data);
        new DownloadImageAsyncTask().execute(weather.iconData);
        return weather;
    }
```

I don't know, how i can fix this. It works ,when i put straight URI like this

```
final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("http://api.openweathermap.org/img/w/13n.png");
```

But if i change it to:

```
public static final String Icon_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/img/w/";
final HttpGet getRequest =new HttpGet(Utils.Icon_URL + code + ".png");
```

That doesn't work anymore. Would be greatful, if someone could help me with that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not sending the parameter correctly on the calling method, which should be something like:

```
new DownloadImageAsyncTask().execute(new String [] { weather.iconData});
```

Try debugging or print the String result of `Utils.Icon_URL + code + ".png"` to check if they match the full URL.